# How to avoid jiggling when working with integer positions?

Tags: graphics, 2d, sdl

I'm working on a 2D game using SDL. One thing that keeps bothering me is that all objects jiggle a bit in relation to each other when the camera is moving slowly.

This is because SDL doesn't support sub pixel positioning, I have to use integers for positioning things on screen.

Here's a quick example of the problem, in case it's not obvious yet. Say I have a side scrolling game where every entity has only an x position:

**Entity positions:**

```
friend.x = 0.1
foe.x = 0.3
```

**What's rendered:**

```
friend.x = 0
foe.x = 0
```

Now let's say the camera is moved to the left by `0.2`:

**Entity positions:**

```
friend.x = 0.1 + 0.2 = 0.3
foe.x = 0.3 + 0.2 = 0.5
```

**What's rendered:**

```
friend.x = 0
foe.x = 1
```

There, it jiggles. Both should have moved minimally, but what's rendered is that `friend` didn't move at all, and `foe` jumped a whole pixel to the right. When the camera moves another `0.2` to the left, `friend` will do the jump and `foe` will stay still. Unfortunately it's actually quite noticeable in practice at low speeds.

The easiest way to mitigate this seemed to be to work with integer positions internally, but I can't really get that to work for my game, just doesn't play well with the physics. I've tried various rounding methods in desperation, but that doesn't seem to change anything in practice. There's still always this jump point when rounding.

So, is there anything I can do to reduce the jiggling? Assuming I'm stuck with both floating point positions and having to work with integers when rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SDL isn't to blame - monitor don't support subpixel positions because, hey, *pixel* definition. In some rare cases you can use pixel components (dots) separately, but this requires knowledge of actual monitor (different colour orders for different monitors, like RGB, BGR, vertical RGB, etc.); this is how subpixel font antialising works. But font is just one colour, on actual image it would produce insane results.

Only adequate solution I see is increasing resolution. Either resolution of monitor, or by rendering image into higher resolution render target and then downsampling it back to monitor resolution with some filtering.

Comment: After accepting this, I found a neat workaround: Just make sure the fractional part of all entity positions moving at the same speed is identical. What I did: 1) All positions in level definition files are now integers. 2) Entities that stop moving snap back to pixel positions. 3) Entities attached to other entities have their fractional part set to the other entity's. Works great!